# How to get image from FileAttachment Annotation in pdf file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf

i am working on PDF annotation app i added PDF file annotation in iPhone it working fine it annotation also visible any reader but facing one issue How to get image from  File Attachment  Annotation in  PDF file whose is created annotation from desktop how can do for this issue

i am using this code for get contents and location of annotation  from  File Attachment  Annotation it working fine

```
CGPDFDictionaryRef pageDictionary = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(pPage);
  //  NSLog(@"%@",(NSDictionary*)pageDictionary);
    CGPDFArrayRef outputArray;
    if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(pageDictionary, "Annots", &outputArray)) {
        [pdfAnnots release];
        return nil;
    }
 CGPDFArrayRef rectArray;
            if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(annotDict, "Rect", &rectArray)) {
                break;
            }

            int arrayCount = CGPDFArrayGetCount( rectArray );
            CGPDFReal coords[4];
            for( int k = 0; k < arrayCount; ++k ) {
                CGPDFObjectRef rectObj;
                if(!CGPDFArrayGetObject(rectArray, k, &rectObj)) {
                    break;
                }

                CGPDFReal coord;
                if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(rectObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeReal, &coord)) {
                    break;
                }

                coords[k] = coord;
            }               

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3]);

            NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

**Update**

```
    CGPDFDictionaryRef aDict;

    if(CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(annotDict, "AP", &aDict)) 
    {

      CGPDFStreamRef textStringRef33;
        if(CGPDFDictionaryGetStream(aDict, "N", &textStringRef33)) {


         UIImage *image= getImageRef(textStringRef33);
            CGPDFDataFormat *format = NULL;

            CFDataRef contdata = CGPDFStreamCopyData( textStringRef33, format );

            NSData *data=(NSData*)contdata;
   }
```

please help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally get solution

```
CGPDFDictionaryRef aDict;
    NSData *imagedata=nil;
    if(CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(annotDict, "FS", &aDict))
    {
        CGPDFDictionaryRef embeddedFiles;
        if (CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary (aDict, "EF", &embeddedFiles) )
        {

            CGPDFStreamRef streamDict;
            if (CGPDFDictionaryGetStream(embeddedFiles, "F", &streamDict))
            {
                CGPDFDataFormat *format = NULL;
                CFDataRef xmlData;

                xmlData = CGPDFStreamCopyData (streamDict, format);
                imagedata=(NSData*)xmlData;

                  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
               savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
               [(NSData*)xmlData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
            }
        }
    }
```